# conflicting types for getline function

Tags: c, makefile

I have a function for getline function in my code block.But while compiling the make file i get the following error:

```
cc -DMAIN   -c -o terp.o terp.c
terp.c:130:15: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
In file included from terp.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:675:20: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here 
make: *** [terp.o] Error 1
```

The part terp.c around 130:

```
 PRIVATE char *getline()
 {
static int first_time_called=1;
if(!first_time_called)
    return 0;
first_time_called=0;
return Expr;
 }
```

Comment: I would be much easier to help if we saw the content of `terp.c` around line `130`.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three possible solutions.

1. As `getline()` is not in standard c library, but in POSIX (and GLIBC), there could be switch to disable its extension (they enabled by default in GCC). Try compiling your source with command `cc -DMAIN -std=c99  -c -o terp.o terp.c`.
2. If you need POSIX extensions, you have to rename your `getline()` function to something else.
3. Remove `#include <stdio.h>` from your source, this error message will disappear. But you may become confused if POSIX's `getline()` is used in your source code, as it will be replaced by yours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a different name for your `getline` function, because there already is a `getline` in the standard clib.